# Adding text to CSS checkbox switch

Tags: html, css

I  am trying to design a checkbox that looks like a switch using only CSS, and keeping as much as possible using `em` so that it can be scaled to any size and still look good.

I've got one looking really sharp, I would just like the ability to add text like "ON" / "OFF" inside the switch itself, and that's where I need your help.

Here's what I have so far:

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rcsngjhm/2/

```css
.switch {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 10px;
}
.cmn-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -9999px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.cmn-toggle + label {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
input.cmn-toggle-jwr + label {
  width: 3em;
  height: 1.5em;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  -webkit-border-radius: 1.5em;
  -moz-border-radius: 1.5em;
  -ms-border-radius: 1.5em;
  -o-border-radius: 1.5em;
  border-radius: 1.5em;
  overflow: hidden;
}
input.cmn-toggle-jwr + label:before,
input.cmn-toggle-jwr + label:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  bottom: 1px;
  content: "";
}
input.cmn-toggle-jwr + label:before {
  right: 1px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  -webkit-border-radius: 1.5em;
  -moz-border-radius: 1.5em;
  -ms-border-radius: 1.5em;
  -o-border-radius: 1.5em;
  border-radius: 1.5em;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: background 0.3s;
  -o-transition: background 0.3s;
  transition: background 0.3s;
}
input.cmn-toggle-jwr + label:after {
  width: 1.5em;
  width: calc(1.5em - 2px);
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  -moz-border-radius: 100%;
  -ms-border-radius: 100%;
  -o-border-radius: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 1px 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -webkit-transition: margin 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: margin 0.3s;
  -o-transition: margin 0.3s;
  transition: margin 0.3s;
}
input.cmn-toggle-jwr:checked + label:before {
  background-color: #8ce196;
}
input.cmn-toggle-jwr:checked + label:after {
  margin-left: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="switch">
  <input id="cmn-toggle-1" class="cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-jwr" type="checkbox">
  <label for="cmn-toggle-1"></label>
</div>
```

Also, if you see any way I can clean this up a bit more, please let me know.

Comment: Do you mean text inside the switch? kind of like this: http://jsfiddle.net/rcsngjhm/3/?

Comment: @ochi Yes, like that. I would just have to tweak it to get it to line up right. EDIT: Ideally, I would like the text to remain there until it's hidden by the switch (not fade out)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I modified the CSS a bit to try to have the text inside the switch.

Depending on how big you want the text to be, you might have to adjust the font-size, margins, etc.

[**See updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rcsngjhm/3/)

```css
.em1-0 {
  font-size: 1em;
}

.em4-0 {
  font-size: 4em;
}

.switch {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 10px;
}

.cmn-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -9999px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.cmn-toggle + label {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

input.cmn-toggle-jwr + label {
  width: 3em;
  height: 1.5em;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  -webkit-border-radius: 1.5em;
  -moz-border-radius: 1.5em;
  -ms-border-radius: 1.5em;
  -o-border-radius: 1.5em;
  border-radius: 1.5em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

input.cmn-toggle-jwr + label:before,
input.cmn-toggle-jwr + label:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  bottom: 1px;
  content: "";
}

input.cmn-toggle-jwr + label:before {
  right: 1px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  -webkit-border-radius: 1.5em;
  -moz-border-radius: 1.5em;
  -ms-border-radius: 1.5em;
  -o-border-radius: 1.5em;
  border-radius: 1.5em;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: background 0.3s;
  -o-transition: background 0.3s;
  transition: background 0.3s;
  /* added these four */
  font-size: 0.75em;
  content:"off";
  text-align: right;
  padding: 0.25em 0.35em;
}

input.cmn-toggle-jwr + label:after {
  width: 1.5em;
  width: calc(1.5em - 2px);
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  -moz-border-radius: 100%;
  -ms-border-radius: 100%;
  -o-border-radius: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 1px 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -webkit-transition: margin 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: margin 0.3s;
  -o-transition: margin 0.3s;
  transition: margin 0.3s;
}

input.cmn-toggle-jwr:checked + label:before {
  background-color: #8ce196;
  /* added these two */
  content: "on";
  text-align:left;
}

input.cmn-toggle-jwr:checked + label:after {
  margin-left: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="switch em4-0">
  <input id="cmn-toggle-0" class="cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-jwr" type="checkbox">
  <label for="cmn-toggle-0"></label>
</div>

<br />

<div class="switch em1-0">
  <input id="cmn-toggle-1" class="cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-jwr" type="checkbox">
  <label for="cmn-toggle-1">on</label>
</div>
```